# React admin interface shows only translation keys

Tags: react-admin

I'm building a react admin app but there seems to be a problem with the translation, I only see translation keys for standard elements
[Translation keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lew8x.png)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource, ListGuesser } from 'react-admin';
import fakeDataProvider from 'ra-data-fakerest';

const fakeData = {
    region: [
        { name: "A" }, { name: "B" }
    ]
}

const dataProvider = fakeDataProvider({ region: fakeData.region }, true);

class App2 extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

    render() {
        return <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
            <Resource name="region" list={ListGuesser} />
        </Admin>
    }
}

export default App2;
```

Comment: It must be something wrong with your setup. We ship the english locale by default. Is this the exact code you are using ?

Comment: I had the same problem after updating to a newer version of react-admin, i do not remember the version number. It might be a version conflict or dependency problem, did you try to remove and reinstall your node_modules?

Comment: I solved the problem after removing a material ui reference from package.json and deleting the node_modules